# Using hepparticles with breqn

Tags: incompatibility, breqn

I want to use the two packages `hepparticles` and `breqn` together in the same document.
But the `hepparticles` package does not seem to work well with `breqn`.
Here is a minimal not-working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
This is the notation for an electron neutrino \HepParticle{\nu}{e}{}.\\
This is the notation for an electron anti-neutrino \HepAntiParticle{\nu}{e}{}.
\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdflatex shows strange symbols for the greek letters `\nu`, although the subscripts "e" are displayed fine.

[image]

The `\HepParticle` command works fine when `breqn` is not used.
Is there a way I can use both packages `hepparticles` and `breqn`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A really minimal example actually doesn't require `hepparticle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

$\mathit{\nu}$

\end{document}
```

If you try it, you'll see the same strange symbol you get with your code, which is the ring accent from the italic font. The fact is that eventually `\HepParticle{\nu}{e}{}` wants to do

```
\mathit{\nu}
```

Such a command would simply produce a standard nu letter, with the default LaTeX setting; `hepparticles` uses this to italicize letters, but not using math italic.

However, `breqn` (or, better, `flexisym`) changes the meaning of `\nu` so that it gives essentially a random result if in the argument to `\mathit`. For very strange reasons, Greek letters are redeclared by `flexisym` to be of type 7 instead of 0, so they obey the current math group.

You can fix `\nu`, but you'll have similar problems with other characters, probably. Look in `cmbase.sym` and copy the offending definitions changing `Var` into `Ord` as I did for `\nu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{breqn}

% Fix the wrong assignment to \nu
\DeclareFlexSymbol{\nu}{Ord}{greek}{17}

\begin{document}
Electron neutrino \HepParticle{\nu}{e}{}.

Electron anti-neutrino \HepAntiParticle{\nu}{e}{}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is clearly a bug of `flexisym`; but I usually recommend against using `breqn` in the first place. A nice idea which simply doesn't work.

---

On the other hand, it seems that at least this example works with `unicode-math`. Compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hepparticles}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Electron neutrino \HepParticle{\nu}{e}{}.

Electron anti-neutrino \HepAntiParticle{\nu}{e}{}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions. I've been also having other compatibility problems between `breqn` and a few other packages, and the more hacks I put in to use `breqn` the more I began to doubt if it's something I should be using. I wonder why many other people regard `breqn` so highly on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @mich I'm not among them. I find it buggy and more difficult to use than manually breaking. It may be beneficial for “automated” typesetting, but the typographic quality is surely not the best.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an alternative to breqn: the [autobreak](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autobreak) package was released recently. It is less sophisticated than breqn, e.g. it requires you to place newlines on possible breakpoints. However, according to my experience, it has less clashes with other packages.